# JQuery Smooth Transition Loading Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to try to load in new content without it being noticeable to the user. I have tried using load() and load() with animation but it still is noticeable. What else can I do so new div content loads seamlessly?

I have as of now:

```
$('#messagefeed').load(document.URL +  ' #messagefeed', function(){
$(this).css('opacity',0).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); });;
```

This just fades in.

(Between I append new elements to the div messagefeed).

Comment: What do you mean by 'without being noticeable to the user'?  If you wanted to user completely unaware of the content, you could keep the div hidden or even possibly avoid loading the new content at all.  If you do want the user to be aware of the content, 'without being noticeable' seems counter-productive.

Comment: As messages come in, you shouldn't be reloading the entire message feed.  You should use something like jQuery's `.get` to only append new messages to what is already there.

Comment: @EricPhillips That is what I ended up doing. Thank you.